# Which design pattern to apply?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am trying to improve my skills with design patterns, so please be easy on me :) In my work I often have to deal with problems where the algorithm is defined, but data structures it is working on are different.

Let's say I have a Counter class, whose responsibility is to simply count items if they match certain criteria (a big simplification). These items may have different structure, so for example:

- if the Counter is running for "text" items, I only count an item if its length is greater than X
- if the Counter is running for "image" items, I only count an item if it's a JPEG image.

It feels right (for me) to have an `AbstractItem` class which the counter would work on, but then it also needs associated `AbstractCriteria`, since criteria are evaluated in different way for each type of item.

Some sort of pseudo code:

```
class Counter
{
  AbstractItemFactory factory; // initialized in constructor
  AbstractCriteria criteria;   // initialized in constructor
  DataProvider provider;       // initialized in constructor

  int count()
  {
    int result;

    while((Data data = provider.get()) != null)
    { 
      AbstractItem item = factory.create(data);
      if(criteria.match(item))
      {
        result++;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

The problem here is that of course `AbstractCriteria` would not know how to handle `AbstractItem`. I know it's possible to solve this by using base-to-derived cast inside overriden `match()` method, but that's not a very good design. It is also possible to use templates, but this will make the code more complicated, so I want to know first if there is any design pattern I could use to achieve what I want. Or maybe my approach to this problem is completely wrong, and there is some easy solution which I just fail to see?

Thanks!

Comment: What about borrowing some functionnal programming techniques and use a boolean lambda expression to represent criterias (a function reference basically)? For instance in JS it would be as simple as:
`function filteredCount(items, filter) {
   return items.filter(filter).length;
} filteredCount([1, 2, 3], function (num) { return num % 2 }); filteredCount(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], function (str) { return str.length >=3 ; });`

Comment: Can the criteria be hard-coded? Or do you want to be able to update criteria without re-compilation, i.e. through configuration files?

Comment: @plalx Unfortunately I am using a typed language, so `function(num)` and `function(str)` would be two different types. In order to use them, I have to make them inherit from some common type. They would also have to accept some abstract type as parameter since you can tell nothing about contents of the item produced by `AbstractItemFactory` in my example. At this point we come back to my original problem: inside of these functions I would have to cast the abstract type back to derived, and I want to avoid that :)

Comment: @denniskb No, criteria can be hardcoded :) I was originally thinking about having them simply as subclasses of `AbstractCriteria` class, with overriden `matches()` method. But then I can't use them in the way I intended :(

Comment: @xba Don't you have generics? Do you need a way to build the filters without knowing anything about the items? If that is the case then the only solution I see would be to use double-dispatch techniques where you have abstract filters e.g. IFilter<-LengthFilter and a method matches(IFilter) on every items. The item would be responsible for supporting the various abstract filter types (e.g. LengthFilter, AttributeFilter) and ignore the unsupported ones.

Comment: @plalx Yes I could use a template to solve this problem, but I wanted to make sure first that there is no other way to achieve it. But thanks for suggestion, I found this `Visitor` pattern which seems to fit my needs :) I will try it out!

Comment: @xba The visitor pattern is basically double-dispatching ;)

Comment: Exactly, I googled it and found this pattern, worked like charm :) Thanks!

Comment: @xba Now add a new type to the data structure and have fun changing all Visitor classes. The Visitor pattern solves the case where you want to extend functionality and not the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved my problem by using Visitor pattern :)

Comment: The Visitor pattern is well suited when you have a data structure and want to be able to add new operations to it. The canonical example is a syntax tree and you want to do operations on the tree, e.g. pretty print, type check etc. However, when the set of algorithms is closed and the data structure changes, the Visitor pattern is a bad choice because changing the data structure implies changing all the Visitors, e.g. when adding a new node type.

Comment: @Jens it worked quite well for me because the number of visitors in my code will always be much lower than number of "elements". Besides that, the my visitor classes need to handle only one "element" class (i.e. if it's a different class, it's an error). So actually I used a modified version of visitor pattern, maybe it's just double-dispatch. But like I said, my skills with patterns are not very good and I'm trying to improve them, so if you have any better solution, I will be happy to take a look :)

Comment: @denniskb Unfortunately I cannot share the code, but it's pretty simple:

Comment: @denniskb I cannot edit my previous comment because apparently "comments may be only edited for 5 minutes"... whatever that means. Unfortunately I cannot share the code, but it's pretty much the same idea as C++ example for visitor pattern on wikipedia :) The only difference is that my `Dispatcher` class implements only one `dispatch` method, for specific type.

Answer (score 0):

KISS

```
template<typename T>
bool predicate(T const & val);

template<>
bool predicate<string>(string const & s) {
    return s.length() > 5;
}

template<>
bool predicate<Image>(Image const & i) {
    return i.format() == "JPEG";
}

template<class Iter>
iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type count(Iter first, Iter last) {
    using element_type = decay<iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>::type;
    return count_if(first, last, predicate<element_type>);
}
```

Put these in a namespace or make them static methods of a counter class if you like.

Comment: That's pretty neat piece of code, I'll keep it in my library for sure :) I was able to compile it after adding a couple of `typename`s here and there. It will however only work if one passes an iterator of a container of specific type. In my case, `AbstractItemFactory` will produce an `AbstractItem` (which would be the parent class for string and Image in your example), so we are back to square one, unless I don't see something obvious...?

Comment: @xba Is there any way for you to query the dynamic/real/derived type of your AbstractItem`s?

Comment: Hello, of course it is possible, I just wanted to avoid that because it's pretty costly operation :) I solved it using visitor pattern in the end :)